# Intermediate steps to illustrate No-Ponzi condition for budget constraint of infinite horizon model (Ramsey Model)

Tags: integration, economics

I am reading Chapter 8 (Ramsey Model) of Introduction to Modern Economic Growth by Daron Acemoglu.

At section 8.1 (page 377), the text introduces a boundary condition for infinite-horizon case, known as No-Ponzi condition. It provides the outline of derivation to illustrate that the boundary condition is necessary, but I am not sure about the intermediate steps (which I appended below).

May I ask how to derive the RHS of equation from the LHS of equation please?

$$\int_0^T c(t) * e^{nt} * e^{-\int_0^t r(s) ds} dt = \int_0^T c(t) * e^{-\int_0^t (r(s) - n) ds} dt$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Use $e^a e^b = e^{a+b}$ and $nt = -\int_0^t -n \; ds$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_0^T c(t) e^{nt} e^{-\int_0^t r(s) ds} \; dt = \int_0^T c(t) e^{-\int_0^t (r(s) - n) ds}  \;dt
$$
using $e^a e^b = e^{a+b}$
$$
\int_0^T c(t) e^{nt-\int_0^t r(s) ds} \; dt = \int_0^T c(t) e^{-\int_0^t (r(s) - n) ds}  \;dt
$$
$$
\int_0^T c(t) e^{\int_0^t n \; ds-\int_0^t r(s) ds} \; dt = \int_0^T c(t) e^{-\int_0^t (r(s) - n) ds}  \;dt
$$
$$
\int_0^T c(t) e^{-\int_0^t -n \; ds-\int_0^t r(s) ds} \; dt = \int_0^T c(t) e^{-\int_0^t (r(s) - n) ds}  \;dt
$$
because integration is a additive operation, for well behaved integrands we can merge the integrals
$$
\int_0^T c(t) e^{-\int_0^t (r(s) -n) \; ds} \; dt = \int_0^T c(t) e^{-\int_0^t (r(s) - n) ds}  \;dt
$$